# How can I run code whenever an NSWindow appears on screen?

Tags: macos, window, nswindow, appkit, nswindowcontroller

I want to run code whenever a particular NSWindow appears on screen, i.e. when it is created and when it is returned to the screen after previously having been removed by a call to `orderOut:`.

I tried implementing `windowDidExpose:` on my Window's delegate, but this was never called, and I found [this old post](https://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2008/Oct/msg02363.html) which explains that this notification is only posted for nonretained windows.

Currently I've done the following:

1. Call my code from the `NSWindowController`'s `windowDidLoad:` method,
2. Subclass `NSWindow` and call the code from both:

   1. `orderFront:`
   2. `makeKeyAndOrderFront:`

   (These two overrides are literally the only code in my subclass.)

This works, but it seems like surely there must be a cleaner way of achieving this. For starters, if it turns out it's possible to bring a window back on screen without either of the two overridden methods being called, then my code will break.

And even if my code is robust, it still seems implausible that you need to implement code in three places just to handle the single conceptual case: "window appears on screen".

Is there some API I'm missing in the docs for this?

Comment: Have you looked into NSWindowDelegate? I think this is what you'll need, check out the "Managing Main Status" section and register for the `windowDidBecomeMain` notification. 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowdelegate

Comment: @theeagle Thanks for the comment. I have been unable to find any `NSWindowDelegate` methods that are always called when the window appears on screen. I discuss `windowDidExpose:` in my question, and your suggestion of `windowDidBecomeMain:` also doesn't work, as it is only called when the window becomes the main window, which will not necessarily happen every time the window appears on screen. In particular, my windows will *never* become main as they return `NO` from `canBecomeMainWindow`.

Comment: There is also the option of doing this via the view, with `viewWillAppear`. Is that a possibility?

Comment: @theeagle That looks like it should work! Unfortunately, the current code does not use view controllers, so might take a bit of work to implement, and as the product for which this code is required has now been released it's going to be hard to find time to try it out unless/until issues are found with the existing solution. Thanks anyway for the suggestion! (And feel free to add it as an answer so you can get some upvotes.)

Comment: One other option, you could override `canBecomeKeyWindow` to return `YES`, and then have your window delegate respond to `windowDidBecomeKey`.

Comment: @theeagle I don't think that's a great solution for the general case, because, much like being main, being key is a distinct state from being on screen, but as it happens it _would_ work for me, and I already have `windowDidBecomeKey` handlers, so I'm not sure why I didn't think of it myself! Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear! Yeah, I think it would be a pretty rare case that you're window goes from not visible to visible and isn't key... but as you said, you might not want to do what you're trying to do *every time* it becomes key.

Answer (score 1):

If your application uses views within the window, you can implement `viewWillAppear` to detect the window becoming visible.

Comment: Worth noting I think that `viewWillAppear` is an `NSViewController` method, so it requires a). OS X 10.10 and b). a view controller to be used!